# detect the jquery object in .data method

Tags: jquery

consider the following code.

```
function createItem(text,event_name, event){
   var rd = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000);
   var item = jQuery('<div/>')
        .css({'padding':padding+'px','cursor':'pointer'})
        .attr({'id':rd});
   jQuery('#selectarea').append(item);
   item.text(text).on(event_name, event);
   return jQuery('#selectarea').find('#'+rd);
}
...
...
 var video = createItem(v, 'click', function(){
                console.log(jQuery(this)); // (1)
                console.log(jQuery(this).data('path')); // undefined
});                         
jQuery.data(video, 'path', v); // (2)
```

I have a `createItem` method which is simply generate the DOM element that responsible for a record item. I need the DOM to memorize some data, so I use `data` method of jquery.

However, it seems the returning DOM is not the same of what `this` is referring to during the click event fires, even I am sure they are the same in view by logging (1) and (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.data()` takes a native DOM node as the first argument, not a jQuery object, so either do

```
jQuery.data(video.get(0), 'path', v);
```

or why not

```
video.data('path', v);
```